# Any way to monitor how much time an encryption program is taking to run using JAVA Eclipse?

Tags: time

I need to see how much time my program is taking, how do I monitor that in Eclipse. Do I need to write an extra bit of code or can I check that on the application itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can get precise result making two measurments:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
//here is your program
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Took "+(endTime - startTime) + " ns");
```

There is no better way to calcute the time of program execution ;)